# Pass information to internal methods: Use fields or parameters?

Tags: oop, architecture

I have a class with a public method that takes a couple of parameters, like this:

The Process method  needs to call different private methods to actually process the data. Is it better to pass all the parameters down the road or should I use a field to provide the information to the private methods?

```
// Variant 1: Parameters
public void Process(string param1, string param2, int param3)
{
   processStep1(param1, param2, param3);
   processStep2(param1, param2);
   processStep3(param1, param2, param3);
}

// Variant 2: Fields
public void Process(string param1, string param2, int param3)
{
   m_Param1 = param1;
   m_Param2 = param2;
   m_Param3 = param3;

   processStep1();
   processStep2();
   processStep3();
}
```

In my eyes the variant 1 has the advantage of being free of side-effects (methods cannot change the value of a field). It mighthave advantages if it comes to unit testing because it's easier to test a specific function.

Variant 2 looks much more clear to me. You don't have to pass any parameters around and it's possible to change the contents of the fields if neccessary.

Is there a clear winner? Are both approaches valid and when to use which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description of your question I'd say Variant 1 is a clear winner, since, as you correctly identified, has more advantages than Variant 2. Side effects and testability are huge factors.

I'd add that Variant 2 is a form of a global state and unnecessary. Why would you want to have member variables used by a method which aren't needed in the object? What kind of object is it? Do you have other methods using these member variables?
Variant 1 has a clear interface for each step and you don't fall into the trap of accessing other state not really available from the parameters.

I'd only choose Variant 2 if the constructor initializes the member variables that are needed for the function process and is only used for this Process method.